# mysql joing tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Here what I would like to pull date from this three table.

Table **users**  has three columns

```
uid, username , data(text)
```

Table **users_order** has three columns

```
uid, orders_id , users_email
```

Table **order_products** has three columns

```
orders_id, product_id, product_name
```

I would like to use `product_id` as the ref/search to pull the user info from those three tables.

If **product_id = 5**

The query will display

`uid; username; users_email; orders_id; product_name; data (text)`

What is the right sql query for this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select a.uid,a.username,b.user_email, b.orders_is, c. product_name
from users a, users_orders b, order_products c
where a.uid = b.uid and b.order_id = c.order_id and product_id = 5
```

this should give what you need

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use two JOINS and a where condition at the end.

- First join on `uid` between **users and users_order** table
- Second join on `orders_id` between **users_order and product_orders**
  table
- and a where condition  `WHERE product_id=5` at end of query.

Use aliases for the table .